# Consuming Rest API via SQLCLR and sending result via SqlPipe

Tags: c#, sql-server, rest, sqlclr

I'm trying to consume a rest/json get api via CLR stored procedure. My problem is that i'm getting only one(last) record.

Here is my code:

```
public partial class StoredProcedures
{
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlProcedure]
    public static void FrtApiJsonGet ()
    {

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("some site");

        var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("login:password");

        request.Method = "GET";
        request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, "Basic " + 
                Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));

        using(HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            using (Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                using (StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream,
                  Encoding.UTF8))
                {
                    string strContent = readStream.ReadToEnd();

                    string value1 = string.Empty;
                    string value2 = string.Empty;
                    string value3 = string.Empty;
                    string value4 = string.Empty;


                    SqlPipe pipe = SqlContext.Pipe;
                    SqlMetaData[] cols = new SqlMetaData[4];
                    cols[0] = new SqlMetaData("value1", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
                    cols[1] = new SqlMetaData("value2", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
                    cols[2] = new SqlMetaData("value3", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
                    cols[3] = new SqlMetaData("value4", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);

                    SqlDataRecord record = new SqlDataRecord(cols);
                    pipe.SendResultsStart(record);

                    var strArray = strContent.Split(new string[] { "{,}" },
                                      StringSplitOptions.None);

                    foreach(var str in strArray)
                    {
                        var subArray = str.Split(',');
                        foreach (var substr in subArray)
                        {
                            if (substr.Contains("\"value1\""))
                                value1 = substr.Split('\"')[3];

                            if (substr.Contains("\"value2\""))
                                callKey = substr.Split('\"')[3];

                            if (substr.Contains("\"value3\""))
                                callPhase = substr.Split('\"')[3];

                            if (substr.Contains("\"value4\""))
                                callresult = substr.Split('\"')[3];
                        }
                        record.SetSqlString(0, new SqlString(value1));
                        record.SetSqlString(1, new SqlString(value2));
                        record.SetSqlString(2, new SqlString(value3));
                        record.SetSqlString(3, new SqlString(value4));

                        pipe.SendResultsRow(record);


                        value1 = string.Empty;
                        value2 = string.Empty;
                        value3 = string.Empty;
                        value4 = string.Empty;
                    }

                    pipe.SendResultsEnd();

                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

I know that the api works and if i try the same code without the sqlpipe in console app it returns a list of values...Yet when used as clr stored procedure i get only one(last) record.

Comment: at first glance it looks correct. there might be an issue with your loops and how you are assigning the values. Include a `pipe.Send(str);` just before the `var subArray = str.Split(',');` so you can see what _should_ be each row.

Comment: Thanks! The problem is in this part: var strArray = strContent.Split(new string[] { "{,}" },StringSplitOptions.None); , string is not splitting here -but i dont know why.

Comment: Do you actually have delimiters in the form of `{,}`? perhaps there is an encoding issue (doubtful, but have to ask). Perhaps there is a "hidden" character in the incoming data that makes it not match _exactly_ to `{,}`? I will post an answer since the overall issue has been identified.

Comment: This should be fairly easy to debug. Create a console app where you have a method mimicking `FrtApiJsonGet` but without the `SqlPipe`, `SqlContext `and all that stuff. You just loop `strArray` and see what you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The overall structure appears to be correct, in terms of the handling of `SendResultsStart`, `SendResultsRow`, and `SendResultsEnd`.

The next place to check is in the loop itself. Quite likely the initial `Split` is not happening as you believe it should be. You should include a `pipe.Send(str);` just before the `var subArray = str.Split(',');` so you can see how the response is being chopped up into rows. This will send each chunk to the "Messages" tab so that you can debug it (same as doing `PRINT` via T-SQL).

Comment: I feel like a complete ass, the problem was truly in the first split - var strArray = strContent.Split(new string[] { "{,}" },StringSplitOptions.None) - the problem was a typo, split should have been { "},{" } and when i was debuging this problem in console app i fixed it there but not in an actual code for clr stored procedure. THANKS ! :)